# ajax with jquery php not working properly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

how exactly ajax jquery working. i am new in ajax and jquery.
i want to delete row my using ajax.
index.php

```
 <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"></head>
    <h1>Login Here</h1>
    <form name="f1" action="login.php" method="post">
    <table border="1">
    <tr><td>username</td><td><input type="text" name="t1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>password</td><td><input type="password" name="t2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
    <td class="error"><?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_detial'])){
        echo "RE-ENTER username and password !! "; }?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

login.php

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function del() {
           var info = 'id=' + id;
              $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'delete.php',
                success: function (result) {
                  $("#div1").html(result);
                }
              });
              return false;

            }



     </script>
    </head>
    <?php
    include "db/db.php";
    $user=$_POST['t1'];
    $pass=$_POST['t2'];

    $result=mysql_query("select * from registor where username='$user' and password='$pass' ")or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    ?>
    <h1>Welcome Mr. <?php echo $user;?></h1>

    <?php
    if(!$user == $row[1] || !$pass ==$row[2]){     //if username or password not matched with database
        header("location:account.php?wrong_detial");
    }

    else{

        if($user == 'admin'){     //if admin login
    ?>
    <table border="1">
    <tr><td>User ID</td><td>Username</td><td>Password</td><td>Email-ID</td><td>delete</td></tr>
    <?php

    $admin_result=mysql_query("select * from registor");
    while($admin_db=mysql_fetch_row($admin_result)){
        ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $admin_db[0];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $admin_db[1];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $admin_db[2];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $admin_db[3];?></td>
    <td id="div1">
    <a href="?delete=<?php echo $admin_db[1];?>" onClick="del()" id="<?php echo $admin_db[1];?>">Delete</a> <!-- Deleting single record-->
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php } 
?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
include "db/db.php";
if($_GET['delete']){
$drop=$_GET['delete'];
}
$result=mysql_query("delete from registor where username='$drop'");
if($result){
echo "deleted";
}
?>
```

what is the solution of this.
is there better way to delete record from database using ajax jquery.

Comment: You asked the same question not 40 mins. ago –^

Comment: what is `var info = 'id=' + id;`supposed to do ?

Comment: missing end curly braces in login.php

Answer (score 0):

Missing end curly braces in `login.php` for `else` block.

```
</table>
   <?php } 
?>
```

should be

```
 </table>
<?php }
  } 
?>
```